# ¿Porque se cierra mi Flujo al seleccionar el metodo que he definido?

Tags: c++, eclipse, stream

Tengo el siguiente Código, al elegir en Switch la opción 1. Ocurre lo siguiente. Que ocurre para que el flujo termine sin dejarme ejecutar el método escribirContacto para rellenar el flujo?

[image: Consola]

He creado el siguiente Metodo escribirContacto para poder crear lineas en mi flujo y registrar informacion:

```
void escribirContacto(){

        ofstream archivo; //Esto es el flujo/fichero de salida.
        string nombreArchivo,texto;
        char respuesta;

        cout<<"Por favor indique el nombre de su archivo"<<endl;
        getline(cin,nombreArchivo);

        archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(),ios::out); 

        if(archivo.fail()){
            cout<<"No se puede abrir el fichero"<<endl;
            exit(1);

        }

        do{

        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"Por favor indique el nombre y telefono del contacto: "<<endl;
        getline(cin,texto);
        archivo<<texto<<endl;

        cout<<"¿Desea guardar otro contacto?"<<endl;
        cin>>respuesta;

        }while((respuesta=='s') || (respuesta=='S'));
 }
```

El main del programa he creado este switch puesto que posteriormente se va a crear un metodo de lectura para el fichero, pero al probar la opcion 1 de añadir contactos directamente salta de la instruccion de indicar el nombre del fichero sin poder poner nada....

```
int main() {
    
    int opc;

    cout<<"1. Añadir Contactos"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Leer Contactos de la Agenda"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"¿Que opcion desea?"<<endl;
    cin>>opc;

    switch(opc){

    case 1: escribirContacto(); break;

    case 2: cout<<"Programa terminado."<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```